# SSIS Project setup

Tags: ssis, msbi

I'm a beginner with the microsoft bi stack - including SSIS. My tests confirm that it is a very good tool.

What I couldn't find out on the fly, however, is whether and how projects can be handled in a team. Is it possible for 2 or more people to share projects? For example, one person prepares the data connections and another person refines the ETL workflow.

How are your experiences at this point.